# What's the penalty for dying in Bioshock 2?

Tags: bioshock-2

I know I I get sent back to a Vita-Chamber.   But does anything else bad happen?   If not, it seems like when you're near one, you're better off dying than using a first aid kit.   I feel like that's probably not correct.   Is dying really so painless?

Comment: That's the way it worked in the first BioShock.  I suck at first person shooters, and I got in the habit of just letting my character die, rather than waste yet another first aid kit.

Comment: There is an achievement for beating Bioshock 1 without using a Vita-chamber, and an option to disable them forcing you to reload a checkpoint upon death in both games. I don't remember that there was anything similar as a reward in Bioshock 2.

Comment: There is also a no-chamber achievement in Bioshock 2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As both Jason and Joshua commented, there is no penalty to dying in bioshock 2.

It kinda ruins the feel of the game but when necessary it is great to have to save a health kit as you referenced.

If you need more information I'm sure I could dig up some other locations that have information on this for you to read through.

Comment: of course you can always make it a personal challenge to not die.

Comment: If you die while harvesting Adam your little sister will be waiting outside the Vita-Chamber and you will have to start harvesting again from scratch.